# Printing utf8 symbols in gdbtui

Tags: c++, linux, utf-8, console, gdb

I have a problem with printing utf8 symbols in gdb -tui mode.

```
(gdb) show charset
The host character set is "auto; currently UTF-8".
The target character set is "auto; currently UTF-8".
The target wide character set is "auto; currently UTF-32".
```

code: tmp.cpp, utf8

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char *s = "asd";
    char *w = "тест";
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << w << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

g++ cmds:

```
g++ -O0 -g tmp.cpp
```

gdb cmds:

```
b 6
r
info locals
```

gdb stdout:

```
s = 0x80487b0 "asd"
w = 0x80487b4 "тест"
```

gdbtui stdout:

```
s = 0x80487b0 "asd"
w = 0x80487b4 "Ð¼Ð°Ð¼Ð°"
```

Tell me please, what should I do, to see the correct output?

Comment: It's a bug. File a bug report, or submit a patch. (IME TUI is full of bugs and unusable in its current state).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ctrl + L resolve this situation.
```